Resizing an image using "ContentScale" in android studio?
hope you're all doing well :)
So I'm currently creating projects in android studio using https://developer.android.com/
but although I thought I understood what was going on, when I change the background image it is unable to be resized?
Original image, sizing perfectly fine:

New image, refusing to be sized properly:

I'm just very confused, the images are both the same size and are both pngs and there is nowhere else where the first image is called that could be messing with it as I tried renaming the second image "androidparty" just to check.
The original code can be found here: https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-compose-add-images
Any help would be appreciated.

Please also provide your own code.

As text, that is, so it can be copied.
